# Intellij, Git/HG ignore, why not write to the .hgignore file?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to get intellij to ignore things to the actual recommended way rather than try to contain it within the project?

As well as other files that Intellij automatically ignores, such as /target and /out.

There is a way to ignore files, why not use that way?

It just makes it very hard to combine Intellij with command line usage like this.

Comment: I'm not aware that intellij automatically ignores target folders when you add the project to Git SCM. The folders are hidden in the project view - but thats about it? the changes view does show target folders if not ignored. So it behaves like a command line. Git status will show the same things you see in intellij.

Comment: hmm ... perhaps my settings are corrupted somehow. I have cleared the ignore settings, but they are still not showing. Perhaps it is the hg4idea plugin that does this automatically?

Comment: maybe. In Project Structure, Modules, Sources. Then on the right the folders are shown (source folder, test sources and excluded folders). The maven folders are detected automatically. Maybe a plugin adds additional folders too. Is the working copy both git and hg? maybe thats confusing the changes view somehow. Probably one wins.